# Как реализовать анимацию плавного морфинга границ изображения?

Tags: javascript, css, svg, анимация, svg-animation

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Есть картинка, при ховере ее границы должны начать хаотично плавать, изгибаться, пока не убран курсор.

Насколько понял, это должно быть связано с svg morphing, но примера не нашел. Только анимация чистой svg, без картинки.
Может у кого есть конкретный пример?

Comment: картинка добавляется одной строчкой, если у Вас уже есть сама анимация пути

Comment: Какой строчкой? Img src? Как связать ее с svg, чтобы был необходимый результат?

Comment: нет в svg есть свой способ встройки картинок `<image xlink:href="..." width="100" height="100"></image>` и на нее маску или clip path с Вашей фигурой

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1144167/188366

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. А варианта с отдельным img нет? В том же picture, например.

Comment: я не понял про отдельные img

Comment: Стоящие вне свг, где-то отдельно в разметке.

Comment: не понимаю зачем, svg - та же разметка

Comment: В свг нельзя вставить picture, чтобы использовать разные форматы под разные нужды. В image можно прописать только одну же картинку

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Решение с помощью SVG mask

Для реализации плавного изменения границ изображения применена анимация маски.
Внутри маски находится path, форма которого будет меняться с помощью анимации атрибута `d`

Техника получения формул path для начального и конечного состояния линии границы изображения приведена в топике [Плавный морфинг одного path в другой path](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1052883/28748)

Используя эти технику вы сможете получить любую собственную форму анимации границ

**1. Пример анимации изменения границы**

Читайте комментарии в коде, надеюсь это поможет понять работу анимации и маски

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="250" height="250"   viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <!-- Ко всему изображению применён чёрный цвет маски, поэтому всё пространство вне элипса становится невидимым -->
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />   
        <!-- Участок изображения ограниченный кривой при fill="white" становится видимым -->
    <path  fill="white" d ="M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z" > 
       <!-- анимация изменения формы границы -->
    <animate
      attributeName="d"
      begin="0s"
      dur="8s"
      repeatCount="indefinite"
      values="
      M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z;
      
     M 18.400548,36.143934 C 9.9101837,13.70807 43.926223,-0.54996925 51.25867,13.455323 c 76.33542,145.803977 86.46964,86.869767 141.28992,2.163965 18.44086,-28.493975 46.29247,8.882468 40.40505,19.210321 -38.20947,67.028001 -97.855,59.568605 -3.94297,138.004111 21.54722,17.99629 -0.61149,66.59059 -19.37585,46.00136 C 198.19796,206.28598 136.75871,43.292058 55.858806,212.92063 41.687846,242.63389 13.162026,189.96512 27.600822,178.74818 116.80291,109.45052 37.717611,87.189447 18.400548,36.143934 Z;
      
      M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z;" 
      />
    </path>
   </mask>
    </defs>  
       <!-- К изображению девушки применена маска -->
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YNh.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"
       pointer-events="fill" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>
```

**2. Пример анимации изменения формы с помощью JS при клике по изображению**

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="250" height="250"   viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <!-- Ко всему изображению применён чёрный цвет маски, поэтому всё пространство вне пр\моугольника становится невидимым -->
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />   
       <!-- Участок изображения ограниченный кривой при fill="white" становится видимым -->
    <path  fill="white" d ="M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z" > 
      
      <!-- Анимация изменения формы границы после клика по изображению -->
    <animate id="open"
      attributeName="d"
      begin="idefinite"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="1"
      fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"
      values="
      M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z;
      
     M 18.400548,36.143934 C 9.9101837,13.70807 43.926223,-0.54996925 51.25867,13.455323 c 76.33542,145.803977 86.46964,86.869767 141.28992,2.163965 18.44086,-28.493975 46.29247,8.882468 40.40505,19.210321 -38.20947,67.028001 -97.855,59.568605 -3.94297,138.004111 21.54722,17.99629 -0.61149,66.59059 -19.37585,46.00136 C 198.19796,206.28598 136.75871,43.292058 55.858806,212.92063 41.687846,242.63389 13.162026,189.96512 27.600822,178.74818 116.80291,109.45052 37.717611,87.189447 18.400548,36.143934 Z" 
      />  
      <!-- Анимация возврата к первоначальной форме границы после повторного клика по изображению -->
      <animate id="close"
      attributeName="d"
      begin="idefinite"
      dur="1s"
      repeatCount="1"
      fill="freeze"
    restart="whenNotActive"
      values="
            M 18.400548,36.143934 C 9.9101837,13.70807 43.926223,-0.54996925 51.25867,13.455323 c 76.33542,145.803977 86.46964,86.869767 141.28992,2.163965 18.44086,-28.493975 46.29247,8.882468 40.40505,19.210321 -38.20947,67.028001 -97.855,59.568605 -3.94297,138.004111 21.54722,17.99629 -0.61149,66.59059 -19.37585,46.00136 C 198.19796,206.28598 136.75871,43.292058 55.858806,212.92063 41.687846,242.63389 13.162026,189.96512 27.600822,178.74818 116.80291,109.45052 37.717611,87.189447 18.400548,36.143934 Z;
      
           M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z" 
      /> 
    </path>
  
 </mask>
    </defs>  
    
       
    
            <!-- К изображению девушки применена маска -->
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YNh.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"
       pointer-events="fill" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>  
<script>
var lion_svg1 = document.getElementById("svg1"),
  close = document.getElementById('close'),
  open = document.getElementById("open");

let flag = true;

lion_svg1.addEventListener('click', function() {
  if (flag == true) {
    open.beginElement();
    flag = false;
  } else {
    close.beginElement();
    flag = true;
  }
}); 
</script>
```

**3. Пример анимации изменения границы после наведения или ухода курсора**

Добавление широкой границы с окраской в красный цвет делает её полупрозрачной
`stroke-width="10"` `stroke="red"`

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="250" height="250"   viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <!-- Ко всему изображению применён чёрный цвет маски, поэтому всё пространство вне пр\моугольника становится невидимым -->
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />   
       <!-- Участок изображения ограниченный кривой при fill="white" становится видимым --> 
         <!-- Добавление широкой границы с окраской в красный цвет делает её полупрозрачной   stroke-width="10" stroke="red" -->
    <path  fill="white" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" d ="M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z" > 
    
      <!-- анимация изменения формы кривой при наведении курсора -->
    <animate id="open"
      attributeName="d"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      dur="0.25s"
      repeatCount="1"
      fill="freeze"
    restart="WhenNotActive"
      values="
      M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z;
      
     M 18.400548,36.143934 C 9.9101837,13.70807 43.926223,-0.54996925 51.25867,13.455323 c 76.33542,145.803977 86.46964,86.869767 141.28992,2.163965 18.44086,-28.493975 46.29247,8.882468 40.40505,19.210321 -38.20947,67.028001 -97.855,59.568605 -3.94297,138.004111 21.54722,17.99629 -0.61149,66.59059 -19.37585,46.00136 C 198.19796,206.28598 136.75871,43.292058 55.858806,212.92063 41.687846,242.63389 13.162026,189.96512 27.600822,178.74818 116.80291,109.45052 37.717611,87.189447 18.400548,36.143934 Z" 
      /> 
     
   <!-- анимация изменения формы кривой при покидании курсора -->
     <animate id="close"
      attributeName="d"
      begin="svg1.mouseleave"
      dur="0.25s"
      repeatCount="1"
      fill="freeze"
    restart="WhenNotActive"
      values="
            M 18.400548,36.143934 C 9.9101837,13.70807 43.926223,-0.54996925 51.25867,13.455323 c 76.33542,145.803977 86.46964,86.869767 141.28992,2.163965 18.44086,-28.493975 46.29247,8.882468 40.40505,19.210321 -38.20947,67.028001 -97.855,59.568605 -3.94297,138.004111 21.54722,17.99629 -0.61149,66.59059 -19.37585,46.00136 C 198.19796,206.28598 136.75871,43.292058 55.858806,212.92063 41.687846,242.63389 13.162026,189.96512 27.600822,178.74818 116.80291,109.45052 37.717611,87.189447 18.400548,36.143934 Z;
      
           M 0.65716244,24.31501 C 0.65716244,12.769206 14.091902,-0.12750335 25.629335,0.31207405 95.055812,2.95723 165.66239,2.95723 224.74955,-0.15260996 236.62119,-0.777431 250.69703,12.426939 250.69703,24.31501 c 0,73.172941 0,139.28327 0,200.43454 0,12.31193 -13.63555,26.2865 -25.94748,26.2865 -63.86693,0 -130.775322,0 -199.120215,0 -12.085756,0 -24.97217256,-14.20074 -24.97217256,-26.2865 0,-61.39127 0,-133.050269 0,-200.43454 z" 
      /> 
    </path>
   </mask>
    </defs>  
           <!-- К изображению девушки применена маска -->
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YNh.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"
       pointer-events="fill" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>
```

**4. Морфинг прямоугольника в овал при наведении курсора**

```html
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     width="250" height="250"   viewBox="0 0 250 250" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >  
 <defs>
  <mask id="msk1">
      <!-- Ко всему изображению применён чёрный цвет маски, поэтому всё пространство вне пр\моугольника становится невидимым -->
     <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="black" />   
       <!-- Участок изображения ограниченный кривой при fill="white" становится видимым --> 
         <!-- Добавление широкой границы с окраской в красный цвет делает её полупрозрачной   stroke-width="10" stroke="red" -->
    <path  fill="white" stroke-width="10" stroke="red" d ="m 249.74954,120.11816 c -0.032,33.80035 0.94749,70.87812 0.71924,101.39854 -0.0941,12.58837 -12.25359,28.03187 -24.83532,28.45154 -32.01304,1.06781 -66.74462,1.86496 -100.05841,-0.0897 -33.048172,-1.93908 -64.250431,1.15753 -99.314815,0.21055 C 18.620731,249.88275 2.7940939,236.54064 2.2155966,225.78362 0.65716244,196.8049 1.3036891,156.87429 1.4005632,122.41823 1.4912502,90.1628 0.65716244,60.443397 2.707633,25.660386 3.3483296,14.791976 15.595091,3.365135 26.481903,3.2644139 59.685029,2.95723 92.106049,2.5598942 124.91789,2.1867235 c 32.54245,-0.370107 66.11789,0.1133441 97.62686,-1.1517993 9.43211,-0.37871659 28.01925,11.9761648 28.05329,24.6882068 0.099,36.962802 -0.81868,62.928765 -0.8485,94.395029 z" > 
    
      <!-- анимация изменения формы кривой при наведении курсора -->
    <animate id="open"
      attributeName="d"
      begin="svg1.mouseover"
      dur="0.5s"
      repeatCount="1"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive"
      values="
      m 249.74954,120.11816 c -0.032,33.80035 0.94749,70.87812 0.71924,101.39854 -0.0941,12.58837 -12.25359,28.03187 -24.83532,28.45154 -32.01304,1.06781 -66.74462,1.86496 -100.05841,-0.0897 -33.048172,-1.93908 -64.250431,1.15753 -99.314815,0.21055 C 18.620731,249.88275 2.7940939,236.54064 2.2155966,225.78362 0.65716244,196.8049 1.3036891,156.87429 1.4005632,122.41823 1.4912502,90.1628 0.65716244,60.443397 2.707633,25.660386 3.3483296,14.791976 15.595091,3.365135 26.481903,3.2644139 59.685029,2.95723 92.106049,2.5598942 124.91789,2.1867235 c 32.54245,-0.370107 66.11789,0.1133441 97.62686,-1.1517993 9.43211,-0.37871659 28.01925,11.9761648 28.05329,24.6882068 0.099,36.962802 -0.81868,62.928765 -0.8485,94.395029 z;
      
     m 221.49156,121.76107 c -0.69227,23.05451 -6.7151,46.60634 -17.68131,66.89751 -6.97552,12.90704 -17.15264,24.69924 -29.43545,32.7231 -14.53539,9.49538 -32.09533,16.21404 -49.45691,16.33934 -16.56191,0.11952 -33.444079,-5.98391 -47.398985,-14.9042 -13.467298,-8.60861 -24.66387,-21.4135 -32.259169,-35.4772 C 34.532257,167.47628 29.118446,144.3228 28.344223,121.76107 27.76932,105.00775 30.919476,87.720522 37.537242,72.318919 45.292705,54.26954 56.430489,36.398301 72.154692,24.622193 87.101007,13.428659 106.24474,5.7671169 124.91789,5.8011169 c 18.87659,0.03437 38.10425,7.9785591 53.2684,19.2202361 14.61764,10.836531 25.23724,27.129484 32.65343,43.745917 7.34348,16.453518 11.19263,34.98401 10.65184,52.9938 z" 
      /> 
     
   <!-- анимация изменения формы кривой при покидании курсора -->
     <animate id="close"
      attributeName="d"
      begin="svg1.mouseleave"
      dur="0.5s"
      repeatCount="1"
      fill="freeze"
      restart="whenNotActive"
      values="
            m 221.49156,121.76107 c -0.69227,23.05451 -6.7151,46.60634 -17.68131,66.89751 -6.97552,12.90704 -17.15264,24.69924 -29.43545,32.7231 -14.53539,9.49538 -32.09533,16.21404 -49.45691,16.33934 -16.56191,0.11952 -33.444079,-5.98391 -47.398985,-14.9042 -13.467298,-8.60861 -24.66387,-21.4135 -32.259169,-35.4772 C 34.532257,167.47628 29.118446,144.3228 28.344223,121.76107 27.76932,105.00775 30.919476,87.720522 37.537242,72.318919 45.292705,54.26954 56.430489,36.398301 72.154692,24.622193 87.101007,13.428659 106.24474,5.7671169 124.91789,5.8011169 c 18.87659,0.03437 38.10425,7.9785591 53.2684,19.2202361 14.61764,10.836531 25.23724,27.129484 32.65343,43.745917 7.34348,16.453518 11.19263,34.98401 10.65184,52.9938 z;
      
           m 249.74954,120.11816 c -0.032,33.80035 0.94749,70.87812 0.71924,101.39854 -0.0941,12.58837 -12.25359,28.03187 -24.83532,28.45154 -32.01304,1.06781 -66.74462,1.86496 -100.05841,-0.0897 -33.048172,-1.93908 -64.250431,1.15753 -99.314815,0.21055 C 18.620731,249.88275 2.7940939,236.54064 2.2155966,225.78362 0.65716244,196.8049 1.3036891,156.87429 1.4005632,122.41823 1.4912502,90.1628 0.65716244,60.443397 2.707633,25.660386 3.3483296,14.791976 15.595091,3.365135 26.481903,3.2644139 59.685029,2.95723 92.106049,2.5598942 124.91789,2.1867235 c 32.54245,-0.370107 66.11789,0.1133441 97.62686,-1.1517993 9.43211,-0.37871659 28.01925,11.9761648 28.05329,24.6882068 0.099,36.962802 -0.81868,62.928765 -0.8485,94.395029 z" 
      /> 
    </path>
  
 </mask>
    </defs>  
            <!-- К изображению девушки применена маска -->
<image id="img1" xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/73YNh.jpg"  width="100%" height="100%"
       pointer-events="fill" mask="url(#msk1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: почему-то рывком прыгает, если убрать не дожидаясь конца анимации

Comment: @Grundy всё верно заметил, в последнем примере да, прыгает и это понятно почему. Установлено фиксированное время для морфинга и если анимацию прервать, то вторая анимация начнется не  с этого же места, а со своей позиции отсюда и рывок. Наверное нужно поставить защиту от прерывания restart="whenNotActive"

Answer (score 8):

В общем smil

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0px auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 150 150" id="svg" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
    <defs>
      <clipPath id="mask">
        <path d="m123.3 221.82a47.625 48.57 0 0 1-47.625 48.57 47.625 48.57 0 0 1-47.625-48.57 47.625 48.57 0 0 1 47.625-48.57 47.625 48.57 0 0 1 47.625 48.57z" fill="none" stroke="#000">
        <animate attributeName="d" 
                 dur="12s"
                 begin="svg.mousemove" 
                 end="svg.mouseout"
                 values="m 123.29583,221.82054 c 0,26.82444 -22.2105,55.34697 -47.625,48.56994 -23.20821,-6.1887 -44.672416,-27.65067 -47.625,-48.56994 -3.748893,-26.56118 21.322438,-48.56994 47.625,-48.56994 26.30256,0 47.625,21.7455 47.625,48.56994 z;
m 123.29583,221.82054 c 0,26.82444 -21.32244,48.56994 -47.625,48.56994 -26.302562,0 -55.96245,-23.07411 -47.625,-48.56994 5.885147,-17.99672 25.450452,-42.37792 47.625,-48.56994 25.33341,-7.0741 47.625,21.7455 47.625,48.56994 z;
m 123.29583,221.82054 c 6.27285,26.08068 -21.32244,48.56994 -47.625,48.56994 -26.302562,0 -47.625001,-21.7455 -47.625,-48.56994 -10e-7,-26.82444 22.703382,-56.98051 47.625,-48.56994 23.884403,8.06053 44.04413,33.68173 47.625,48.56994 z;
m 123.29583,221.82054 c 5.53265,28.52679 -13.8157,50.87971 -47.625,48.56994 -26.241395,-1.79275 -47.625001,-21.7455 -47.625,-48.56994 -10e-7,-26.82444 21.322438,-48.56994 47.625,-48.56994 26.30256,0 42.51769,22.2362 47.625,48.56994 z;
m123.3 221.82a47.625 48.57 0 0 1-47.625 48.57 47.625 48.57 0 0 1-47.625-48.57 47.625 48.57 0 0 1 47.625-48.57 47.625 48.57 0 0 1 47.625 48.57z"
                 repeatCount="indefinite"/>
      </path>
   </clipPath>
    </defs>
    
     <g transform="translate(0,-147)">
     <image href="https://sun9-72.userapi.com/c824600/v824600327/19d5b5/4kUSTPvShoQ.jpg?ava=1" 
           x="0" y="150" 
           width="150" height="150"
           clip-path="url(#mask)"
          preserveAspectRatio="none"/>
     </g>
    
    

  </svg>
</div>
```

Answer (score 6):

Простой вариант на CSS с использованием "псевдо-маски" сделанной из картинки с прозрачной "кляксой".
"Псевдо-маска" идёт поверх изображения, изначально со свойством `scale(2)`, при наведение на родителя применяется `scale(1)`.

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image .pseudo-mask {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/nj9o1MA.png') no-repeat center center / 100% 100%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2);
  transition: all .3s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.image:hover .pseudo-mask {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1);
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="pseudo-mask"></div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5NBOFbo.png">
</div>
```

---

С анимацией вращения после наведения.

Придётся увеличить размер картинки, так, чтобы сама "клакса" осталась того же размера, а её фон стал больше. Я увеличил в .5 раз, от предыдущего размера.
После этого придётся изменить начальный `scale(2)`, на 2.5, и конечный на 1.5.

После добавить анимацию вращения, учитывая предыдущие записи в `transform`.

Получается как-то так:

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image .pseudo-mask {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/cmz0d0O.png') no-repeat center center / 95% 95%;
  /* Пришлось немного уменьщить размер, чтобы не вылезало за края */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(2.5);
  transition: all .3s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.image:hover .pseudo-mask {
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5);
  animation: pseudo-mask-rotate 30s .3s linear infinite;
  /* .3s это задержка, чтобы анимация "появления" при наведение отработала нормально, а после началось вращение */
}

@keyframes pseudo-mask-rotate {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) scale(1.5) rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="pseudo-mask"></div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5NBOFbo.png">
</div>
```

Но есть минус, когда `:hover` сбрасывается, сбрасывается и резко анимация..

Всё что смог придумать, переделать `scale()` на `width` и `height`:

```css
.image {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
}

.image .pseudo-mask {
  display: block;
  width: calc(100% * 2.5);
  height: calc(100% * 2.5);
  background: url('https://i.imgur.com/cmz0d0O.png') no-repeat center center / 95% 95%;
  /* Пришлось немного уменьщить размер, чтобы не вылезало за края */
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  transition: all .3s linear;
  z-index: 1;
}

.image > img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
  border: 0;
  border-radius: 20px;
}

.image:hover .pseudo-mask {
  width: calc(100% * 1.5);
  height: calc(100% * 1.5);
  animation: pseudo-mask-rotate 30s .3s linear infinite;
  /* .3s это задержка, чтобы анимация "появления" при наведение отработала нормально, а после началось вращение */
}

@keyframes pseudo-mask-rotate {
  100% {
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%) rotate(1turn);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="image">
  <div class="pseudo-mask"></div>
  <img src="https://i.imgur.com/5NBOFbo.png">
</div>
```

Comment: а если ее еще крутануть в момент анимации...

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, принято, чуть позже дополню ответ

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, обновил, лучше?)

Comment: ну вот ведь поинтереснее, еще предлагаю не останавливать скейл и колбасить его туда сюда в небольших пределах, причем по x и y на разные величины

Comment: а второй плюс от меня Вы не получите, уж извиняйте :D