# Как можно создать вращающуюся рамку в css, которая будет обрезать изображение?

Tags: html, css, svg, less

[image: Само изображение и рамка выглядят таким образом.]

Это должно выглядеть как на изображении ниже, но кроме того необходимо, чтобы при наведении эта рамка сложной формы вращалась на 360 градусов.(изображение животного имеет прямоугольную форму и размеры больше размеров рамки)
Я пробовал это сделать следующим образом:

1)

```
HTML

<div class="img-wrapper">
  <img src="assets/img/pets-in-zoo/panda.svg" alt="panda" class="pet-pic">
</div>
```

```
CSS

.img-wrapper {
   width: 331.9px;
   background: url(assets/img/pets-in-zoo/img-wrapper.svg);
   overflow: hidden;
}
```

2. 

```
HTML

<div class="img-wrapper">
</div>
```

```
CSS

.img-wrapper {
   width: 331.9px;
   background: url(assets/img/pets-in-zoo/panda.svg) no-repeat center/cover;
   -webkit-image-mask: url(assets/img/pets-in-zoo/img-wrapper.svg);
}
```

3. 

```
HTML

<div class="img-wrapper">
</div>
```

````
CSS

.img-wrapper {
   width: 331.9px;
   background: url(assets/img/pets-in-zoo/panda.svg) no-repeat center/cover;
}
.img-wrapper::before {
  width:100%;
  height: 100%;
  background: url(assets/img/pets-in-zoo/img-wrapper.svg) no-repeat center/cover;
  mix-blend-mode: screen;
}
``` этот способ я сам не понял, но попробовал, однако все так-же не работает.
````

Comment: Думаю этот ответ подойдёт - [Как реализовать анимацию плавного морфинга границ изображения?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1149010/221218)

Comment: @CbIPoK2513 там svg в тегах нету такого

Comment: @MaximLensky Привет Макс. Может поговорим, приглашаю в чат

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> необходимо, чтобы при наведении эта рамка сложной формы вращалась на
> 360 градусов

Совсем простой вариант:

```css
body{padding:0;overflow:hidden;}

.item {
  position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 180px; height: 180px;
  border-radius: 120% 120% 170% 100% / 120% 120% 150% 150%;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.item::before {
  content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwNLWXw1UnVIqUZu9Kj3qEMX3HkXv7ry4NQq5W7=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo); background-size: cover;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.item:hover {transform: rotate(360deg);}
.item:hover::before {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Вариант чуть интереснее:

```css
body{padding:0;overflow:hidden;}

.item {
  position: relative; overflow: hidden; width: 180px; height: 180px;
  border-radius: 120% 120% 170% 100% / 120% 120% 150% 150%;
  background: url(https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwNLWXw1UnVIqUZu9Kj3qEMX3HkXv7ry4NQq5W7=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo); background-size: cover;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.it {
  content: ""; position: absolute; top: -10px; left: -10px; right: -10px; bottom: -10px;
}

.it::before {
  content: ""; position: absolute; top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
  background: url(https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwNLWXw1UnVIqUZu9Kj3qEMX3HkXv7ry4NQq5W7=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo); background-size: cover;
  transition: transform 2s;
}

.item:hover {transform: rotate(360deg);}
.it:hover::before {transform: rotate(-360deg);}
```

```html
<div class="item"><div class="it"></div></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Обычный border-radius и ни какого svg

```css
.item {
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 49% 51% 50% 50% / 86% 32% 68% 14%;
  background: url(https://yt3.ggpht.com/a/AATXAJwNLWXw1UnVIqUZu9Kj3qEMX3HkXv7ry4NQq5W7=s900-c-k-c0xffffffff-no-rj-mo);
  background-size: cover;
  animation: move 5s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes move {
  0% {
    border-radius: 62% 38% 50% 50% / 27% 46% 54% 73%;
  }
  50% {
    border-radius: 62% 38% 80% 20% / 27% 69% 31% 73%;
  }
  75% {
    border-radius: 37% 63% 35% 65% / 66% 39% 61% 34%;
  }
  100% {
    border-radius: 62% 38% 80% 20% / 49% 39% 61% 51%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="item"></div>
```

Answer (score 2):

### mask SVG

Создаем `path` по форме рамки, включаем его в SVG mask и обрезаем область изображения, которая находится вне маски.

```html
<style>
.img {
mask:url(#msk);
}
</style>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" version="1.1">
 <mask id="msk" > 
   <path id="p1" fill="white" d="M76.7 51.8C139.6 18.4 125.8 108.9 278.6 44 360.8 9.2 394.4 244.4 327.8 304.7 268.8 358.2 149.9 378 89.9 325.7 21 265.6-4 94.8 76.7 51.8Z" > 
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 200 200;360 200 200" dur="4s" begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" /> 
  </path>
</mask> 

 <image class="img"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYOzh.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
</svg>
```

*Вариант с полупрозрачным фоном*

Добавляем в определение маски

`<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" />`, что делает фон полупрозрачным

```html
<style>
.img {
mask:url(#msk);
}
</style>
<svg id="svg1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"  xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="400" height="400" viewBox="0 0 400 400" version="1.1">
 <mask id="msk" > 
   <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="red" /> 
 <path id="p1" fill="white" d="M76.7 51.8C139.6 18.4 125.8 108.9 278.6 44 360.8 9.2 394.4 244.4 327.8 304.7 268.8 358.2 149.9 378 89.9 325.7 21 265.6-4 94.8 76.7 51.8Z" > 
   <animateTransform attributeName="transform" type="rotate" values="0 200 200;360 200 200" dur="4s" begin="svg1.mouseenter" end="svg1.mouseleave" /> 
  </path>
</mask> 

 <image class="img"  xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/MYOzh.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" /> 
</svg>
```